# Filtering on date

Tags: date, filter, google-sheets

I input work startdate in A Section (like `20-10-2016`), 
then I input expected end date in B Section (like `0-10-2016`), and
in C Section I would like for an automatic text to show depending on whether the date in A Section isn't here yet ("not started"), and if date in A Section has passed, and we're in the middle of the date-span in A Section and B Section (like, for the example above, `25-10-2016`), have C Section say ("in progress"), and if date in B Section has passed, have C Section say ("job finished").

How I can make this happen in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`TODAY()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984) function which tells you the current day.  With a few `IF` statements you can display the text you want based on whether the current date is before the start date or after the end date.